# Forbidden vs. allowed transitions

Tags: solid-state-physics, definition, semiconductor-physics, fermis-golden-rule

In Chapter 1 of his [*Semiconductor Devices*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471143235) text, Sze gives a crash course (being generous) on solid state physics. At one point, Sze talks about two classes of transitions:

1. Allowed direct
2. Forbidden direct

I am familiar with direct band gaps, but have never heard this additional distinction of allowed versus forbidden. Can anyone point me to what this means? In the 4th edition it is Fig. 31 which shows the mechanisms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Allowed* and *Forbidden* transition is the language related to the [*selection rules*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule). If we look at it from the point of view of Fermi Golden rule:
$$
w_{i\rightarrow f}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\left|V_{if}\right|^2\delta\left(E_f-E_i\pm\hbar\omega\right),$$
then the transition probability may be zero for two reasons:

- the energies do not match, i.e., $E_f-E_i\neq\pm \hbar\omega$
- the matrix element is zero, i.e., $V_{fi}=0$

In the second case we say that transition is *forbidden* - it cannot happen, even if the energies match. Many transitions are forbidden due to symmetries of the orbitals or conservation of angular momentum (spin selection rules.)

Saying that *transition is forbidden* or *allowed* is not the same as saying *forbidden/allowed transition*: *forbidden transition* suggests that the transition does happen, which seems like a contradiction. In fact, the transition that seems to be forbidden may actually happen due to some interaction that was not taken into account or in higher orders of the perturbation theory (i.e., going beyond the basic FGR formula given above.)

For more information, examples, and references I suggest consulting Wikipedia article [*Forbidden mechanism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_mechanism).

Comment: One useful way to understand the phenomenon more deeply is to take a course on Group Theory (this is how my professor of solid state optics went around this) http://www.th.physik.uni-bonn.de/nilles/people/luedeling/grouptheory/data/grouptheorynotes.pdf you can find here a "group theory for physicists" which I still find a bit dense, but if you have in mind the crystalline structure of semiconductors you will be able to build the blocks to understand selection rules better.

Comment: @ondas this looks like a comment on the question than on my answer.